# Show this element without having code repeating each time

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, this

I'm showing / hidding data from Json on click of a marker which is working totally great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a shorter way you can iterate over the `json` object keys using [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
$.getJSON('js/data.json', function (json) { // <-- json variable
  Object.keys(json).forEach(function (country) {
    $(".marker." + country.toLowerCase()).on("click", function () {
      $("#show").html(
        "Image: <img src=" + json[country][0].image + ">" +
        "| Description: <h1>" + json[country][0].description) + "</h1>";
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: that work as well and is shorter ! Thanks a lot, sorry  ill accept answer from Icepickle as he poster first, but realyl appreciate !

Comment: @thibault423 You shouldn't care about timings, his answer avoids the need to bind the property, so I wouldn't mind if this is the answer ;)

Comment: @Icepickle If you don't mint then =) Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by looping over the properties in your json object like so

```
var json = {
  "France": [{
    "image": "img/ausralia.jpg",
    "description": "number django 1"
  }],
  "Australia": [{
    "image": "img/ausralia.jpg",
    "description": "number django 2"
  }]
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  // iterate all properties in the json object
  for (var prop in json) {
    if (json.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      // add the marker items
      $(".marker." + prop.toLowerCase()).on("click", function( country ) {
        $("#show").html(
          "Image : <img src=" + json[country][0].image + ">" +
          "| Description : <h1>" + json[country][0].description) + "</h1>";
      }.bind( this, prop) ); // prop needs to be bound so that the correct country is triggered
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Icepickle, THis just trigger the data from Australia :/

Comment: @thibault423 Oh sorry, that was because I forgot to see the callback ;) I now bound prop to the onclick function so you should see now both countries ;)

Answer (score 0):

One Last thing i'm trying to do is to call the Json Data from an external file

I tried to wrap the functio into

```
   $.getJSON('js/data.json', function(data) {
```

without success...

it's telling me on the line that json is not defined ( in the console)

```
Object.keys(json).forEach(function (country) {
```

any idea ?

Thanks a lot !

--UPDATE JSON STRUCTURE ----

```
{
    "france": [
        {
            "image": "img/ausralia.jpg",
            "description": "number django 1",
        }
    ],
       "australia": [
        {
            "image": "img/ausralia.jpg",
            "description": "number django 2",
        }
    ],

         "uk": [
        {
            "image": "img/ausralia.jpg",
            "description": "number django 3",
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: In that case you have to use `data` instead of `json`

Comment: hm I tried  to replace  $getJSON by  $getdata and Object.keys(json) by Object.keys(data) and I'm still having the same error :/

Comment: Do: `$.getJSON('js/data.json', function(json) { // solution code here });`

Comment: still remaining :(

Comment: thanks, the error disappear but now i don't have any data display on click :( :( Really appreciate your time and help by the way !!

Comment: Not to nitpick, but this should have been a new question, or you should have edited your original question (though since you already had an answer, creating a new question and linking to this one would have been better). For now (since @YosvelQuintero already updated his answer) you can just edit your question, and delete this answer ;)

Comment: ow ok I see, sorry about that !!!

I made it work, it was my json structure wrong !

Thanks a lot !